# Python pandas.read_csv() quotes and separator in one line without escapechar

Tags: python, pandas, quotes, separator

I have csv file with, where quotes and separator (comma) can be inside quote like this:

```
Id,Name,Other
1,"Matt"hew","a,bc"
```

I understand, that it will be easy with escaprechar in the csv file, but actual working file is
50 000 rows and near 100 columns and it is not possible to do it manually.

If I use:

```
 pandas.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',', quoting=3)
```

I receive the following output:

```
1|"Matt"hew"|"a
```

If I use another quoting (0, 1, 2), I receive:

```
1|Matthew"|a,bc
```

But I need the output like this:

```
1|Matt"hew|a,bc
```

Comment: That's not a valid CSV file.  There's never a general rule for fixing invalid files.  You may need to write a separate script to fix up the quotes using one of the acceptable methods, like `"Matt""hew"` or `"Matt\"hew"`.

Comment: I solved this issue using following method:
I careted temp file from the original, which adds escapechar="\" before any quotes, which is not near comma and it works perfectly